# Setting up ProGuard with Android Library Projects

Tags: android, proguard

I'm trying to setup proguard for my Android project. My application project has very little code in it, but references a library project which has the vast majority of the code and any other external jars. That being said, I'm not sure how to setup proguard to take this into account. Right now my proguard config file is just the Android example from [the ProGuard site](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication). I've been searching around, but haven't found a lot or any documentation on using proguard with library projects, just jars. I'm new to proguard, so any push in the right direction would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit**

As @BornToCode points out, a different answer (originally posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982344/is-proguard-cfg-needed-for-library-projects#10992604)) better explains how library projects are handled by *Proguard*. Additionally, this referenced question has more interest and more overall reputation than that linked in my original response. *The quote:*

> Library projects by themselves don't run ProGuard, so they don't use
>   any configuration.
>
> Application projects obfuscate the entire code base, including any
>   referenced libraries, so they need proper configuration for the
>   application code and for the library code.

---

**Old Answer** *(not wrong, just probably not the best approach)*

The library projects is more of a convenient way of linking a project to its jar in Eclipse. When you build the project, the only component of the library project that is visible to your compiler is the jar file.

If you want to obfuscate that jar, check out this post:

[How to obfuscate an Android library (.jar file) using Proguard in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088958/how-to-obfuscate-an-android-library-jar-file-using-proguard-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi, it seems this answer is different with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982344/is-proguard-cfg-needed-for-library-projects#10992604). Could you explain?

Comment: @BornToCode you are absolutely right. The linked response is obviously much more reputable than my answer. I have added a link to this and a quote in my answer here.

Answer (score 20):

It makes sense to me to specify proguard settings for a library (like which library files shouldn't be obfuscated) *in the library project*. I've found that I also need to include proguard configurations from my library modules in my application. To do this, I added the following to the `defaultConfig` section in my library's `build.gradle`

```groovy
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    defaultConfig {
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

and then configured the proguard-rules.pro file in my library module to keep the names of important serialized classes.

See also [`consumerProguardFiles` gradle reference](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.html#com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType:consumerProguardFiles)