# Android studio unable to locate project library

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.9

Recently, I in the process of migrating Eclipse project into Android studio project. I begun with `File -> Import Project...`

I encounter a very strange problem, where Android studio unable to compile my main project, due to **cannot find symbol**. Those symbols suppose to found in one of my library projects : https://code.google.com/p/android-lockpattern/ (version 3.0.1)

These is one of the error messages

```
C:\projects\xxx.java:4: error: cannot find symbol 
import group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.prefs.DisplayPrefs;
```

These are my strange observation

### I can confirm no error while building androidlockpattern

```
:androidlockpattern:compileLint
:androidlockpattern:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:preBuild
:androidlockpattern:preReleaseBuild
:androidlockpattern:checkReleaseManifest
:androidlockpattern:preDebugBuild
:androidlockpattern:preDebugTestBuild
:androidlockpattern:prepareComActionbarsherlockActionbarsherlock440Library UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:prepareReleaseDependencies
:androidlockpattern:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:compileReleaseJava UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:proguardRelease UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:packageReleaseJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:androidlockpattern:bundleRelease
```

### My main project does include androidlockpattern as module

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':androidlockpattern')
    ...
```

### Android studio editor can recognize androidlockpattern. No red line highlighted

[image]

### I have other library projects. They all compiled together well with my main project. The only error so far is androidlockpattern.

Here's are the detailed error message

```
C:\projects\xxx.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
import group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.prefs.DisplayPrefs;
                                                  ^
  symbol:   class DisplayPrefs
  location: package group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern.prefs
C:\projects\xxx.java:195: error: cannot find symbol
            Intent intent = new Intent(LockPatternActivity.ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN, null,
                                                          ^
  symbol:   variable ACTION_COMPARE_PATTERN
  location: class LockPatternActivity
C:\projects\xxx.java:198: error: cannot find symbol
            DisplayPrefs.setMaxRetry(this, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            ^
  symbol:   variable DisplayPrefs
  location: class JStockFragmentActivity
C:\projects\xxx.java:199: error: cannot find symbol
            intent.putExtra(LockPatternActivity.EXTRA_PATTERN, startupLockPattern);
                                               ^
  symbol:   variable EXTRA_PATTERN
  location: class LockPatternActivity
C:\projects\xxx.java:1239: error: cannot find symbol
            case LockPatternActivity.RESULT_FAILED:
```

For `build.gradle` of `androidlockpattern`, it looks like the following

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "group.pals.android.lib.ui.lockpattern"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 10
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard true
            proguardFiles 'proguard.cfg'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
}
```

Here's my project settings. Seems fine to me.

[image]

Any idea what other steps I can take, to diagnostic the root cause?

Comment: How does your build.gradle for the module look like?

Comment: Change `targetSdkVersion 10` to `targetSdkVersion 19` :)

Comment: Maybe you're overriding the target somewhere else. Like in the manifest or something. Should I post an answer with it?

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. Same error still...

Comment: Have you tried disabling runProguard? and make sure you syncronize your projects with Gradle+Clear project.

Comment: @PedroOliveira Using `runProguard false` in androidlockpattern's `build.gradle` does solve my problem. Would you like to post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acording to Android docs:

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by
>   removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with
>   semantically obscure names.

Change `runProguard true` to `runProguard false`

If you want to run Proguard on your project you should change the `proguard.cfg` accordingly.

This bug may also apply to you: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=52962

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what Android Studio chooses to turn on proguard for project library, imported directly from Eclipse. It seems that, project library shouldn't turn on proguard : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15166380/setting-up-proguard-with-android-library-projects

Comment: This is another answer, regarding whether to run proguard for library project. The answer is from proguard author himself :) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10982344/is-proguard-cfg-needed-for-library-projects?lq=1

Answer (score 1):

- Remove your library, delete them from the project.
- Copy it to "app"/libraries/
- Go on File -> Import Module, select the library inside libraries folder.
- Add line -> compile project(':your_library_folder_name') to build.gradle.
- Sync gradle.
- Build project.