# Using proguard for Library Projects

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard, reverse-engineering

I have a library A which is inherited by library B and a project C uses Library B. I want to obfuscate the code of library A and B in C's proguard configuration file. Currently All library code is visible in the reverse engineered project C. Anyone who reverse engineers my code is able to see the Library A code and LIbrary B code but the wrapper code is only obfuscated. Kindly suggest how to proceed on this.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088958/how-to-obfuscate-an-android-library-jar-file-using-proguard-in-eclipse