# Gradle - Are proguard configurations inherited?

Tags: android, gradle, proguard

This might be too broad, but I would like an explanation on how Proguard and minification configurations are passed between projects and their dependencies to understand how deeply are these operations made in my project's dependency tree.

I have on `build.gradle` of `themodule':

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        }
dependencies {
    compile project(':someothermodule')
    compile 'some.maven.central.library'
}
```

By the configuration it seems clear that the classes inside `themodule` will be minifyed and obfuscated, but what happens with the classes of `someothermodule`? Will they also be minifyed and obfuscated? Even if `someothermodule` has `minifyEnabled true`?

What happens if 'someothermodule' is just a .jar dependency?

What happens with the configurations of `some.maven.central.library`?

Are the Proguard configurations of the module being built cascading down to its dependencies or each of them follows its own rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, it is the following :

> Library projects by themselves don't run ProGuard, so they don't use
>   any configuration.
>
> Application projects obfuscate the entire code base, including any
>   referenced libraries, so they need proper configuration for the
>   application code and for the library code.

I had a small case where I had a Facebook library as a gradle dependency and since we were obfuscating the code with `minifyEnabled:true` we had to keep all its code from being obfuscated, using the regular keep commmands such as :

```
-keep class com.facebook.** { *; }
```

Additionally, and regarding the .jar obfuscation, you can check [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088958/how-to-obfuscate-an-android-library-jar-file-using-proguard-in-eclipse)

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

If a module get obfuscated (`minifyEnabled true`) by itself, the used configuration is not automatically inherited by the consuming module (in your case the application).

There is a mechanism in the Android gradle plugin to enabled this:

```
consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

The rules that are contained in `proguard-rules.pro` will be automatically included in the application project and merged with other configuration files.

This will only work for Android library projects (`.aar`). If you have a dependency to a `.jar` file on `maven central` for example, no such consumer rules will be available, and you have to add the needed configuration to your application project yourself.

Keep in mind that the configuration to obfuscate a module and the one used by the consuming application / module does not need to be identical. The consumer rules will in most cases only be a set of `-keep` rules.